# How to apply settings not only to the current user

Tags: macos, user-profiles

A problem I have with Mac OS X is that every time a new setting is added, it applies only for the current user. For example, if I add a new keyboard layout, I have to go to every user and make them have the new keyboard layout. The same for the monitor arrangement, or even if the switch user option shall be on the menu bar.
Is there a way I can force to every user to follow the new settings?

Comment: That's a 'problem' with every OS, user settings are not global. You'd probably need an MDM/profile solution to do this; in effect take global charge of all users from a central account.

Comment: @Tetsujin How can I create a MDM/profile solution?

Comment: see https://www.jamf.com